# pt-query-digest : unable to use --review command properly

Tags: pt-query-digest

I am using the following command to log the results of pt-query-digest into mysql test.query_review table

pt-query-digest D=test,t=query_review /home/dbadmin/devmysql1-slow.log

Some imp points for this 
1) I am logged in linux machine as root user and using the above command line of root user.
2) no such user exist for mysql db(there is another set of user name and pwd , that I use to login into mysql)

Its giving me access denied for root user.

I wanna know, where and how to give the user name n pwd of mysql user with exact syntax so that this command runs and logs in data into target table

Answer (score 0):

After the explain switch you need the dsn (a string that gives connection information)

--explain h=localhost,u=*account*,p=*password*

Use --ask if you have Term::Readkey installed to avoid printing the password on the screen and in your history.

Here's the [percona documentation on DSN's](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/dsn_data_source_name_specifications.html) for Percona Toolkit and its ancestor Maatkit.